# Proper usage of linux mdraid spare-group

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm, mdraid

I'm going to create two raid1 arrays, lets say:

- 2x1tb - `/dev/md1`: `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc`
- 2x2tb - `/dev/md2`: `/dev/sdd`, `/dev/sde`

My idea is to use one additional 2tb hdd `/dev/sdf` as hot spare which will be shared by these two arrays and by used by first one with problem.

I was looking for informations how to create such configuration and found almost no examples of setups.

Documentation of [mdadm.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/mdadm.conf) describes `spare-group` option:

> The value is a textual name for a group of arrays. All arrays with the same spare-group name are considered to be part of the same group. The significance of a group of arrays is that mdadm will, when monitoring the arrays, move a spare drive from one array in a group to another array in that group if the first array had a failed or missing drive but no spare.

However I've never edit `/etc/mdadm.conf` manually yet. I've always used `mdadm` command to manage md configurations. [mdadm docs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm) ment `spare-group` keyword by I think there is no way to configure it using this tool. So my plan is:

1. Crate two arrays `/dev/md1`, `/dev/md2` using `mdadm`.
2. Edit `/etc/mdadm.conf` and add `spare-group` parameters to both definitions of arrays.
3. Add spare disk to one of these to arrays using `mdadm`.

I admit I haven't tested this yet. Due to lack of informations I would like to ask do you have any experience with shared spares in mdraid? Is it reliable? Is my vision how to configuration it correct? Alternatively I consider simple bash script in 1 minute cron with will check both arrays status and spare to one of it post-fact after any member fail.

BTW: Chat GPT says there is no such option as `spare-group` in mdraid configuration.